# "ImportError: *.so: cannot open shared object file" after pip installing extension module built with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm running into some peculiar behavior that I don't understand. I have a python/C++ module (call it X) built using pybind11. In my build directory I have

```
build
|- X
   |- a.so
   |- b.so 
   |- X.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so (which depends on a.so and b.so)
```

When I'm in my build directory, `python -c "import X"` works, which is great.

Then, I generated a whl file for my module, and pip installed it in my virtualenv, so I have the same files above installed in `~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/X`. However, `python -c "import X"` then resulted in "ImportError: a.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory", so presumably the `X.cpython*.so` was loaded, but the OS doesn't know where to load the dependent `.so` files (`a.so, b.so`).

As a workaround, I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/X`, and it resolves the issue, but I don't think that's the proper way. Can someone shed some light on why this is happening and the proper way to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/where-do-executables-look-for-shared-objects-at-runtime) and references therein. In this case you will want to add `-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN` to the extra linker arguments when defining your extension e.g.

```
Extension(Extension(
    'X',
    sources=[ ... ]
    extra_link_args=['-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN', ... ]
    ... 
)
```

Comment: Thanks @ChrisD, I've updated my cmake build to use -DCMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH=TRUE and -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH=@ORIGIN